# Connecting to sql server 2005 remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, remote-access

I am new to sql server and was wondering if anyone can recommend any good articles on to setup the server so I can browse the database remotely with management studio and allow a program to connect remotely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the database if you have rights to access to the database. please contact the DBA, he will grant you access.